Nagios XI License Key
I need to automate the deployment of Nagios XI but I can not find where to configure the License Key or Configure license in non-interactive way.I only found the interactive way to do it through the web server interface but I would need to do it via file/mysql/api...
All I found is some empty rows on mysql table (xi_options): trial_key enterprise_key
but it seems not to affect on configuration.
